# Making Mailchimp pop-up work on-click for Jekyll/Github Pages

Tags: javascript, popup, jekyll, mailchimp, github-pages

Trying to make Mailchimp's pop-up form work on-click for my Jekyll Powered Github Page.

Steps I've followed:

1. I've created a link on my site to trigger the pop-up with:

   ```html
   <a href="#" id="open-popup" onclick ="showMailingPopUp(); return false;">Join Newsletter</a>
   ```

   The above sits in the HTML for my navigation bar (`masthead.html`).
2. I've then created an HTML for the mailchimp pop-up code (`newsletter.html`). And yes, uuids and lids were replaced by my own hashes

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
   <script>
     function showMailingPopUp() {
       require(
         ["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"],
         function(L) {
           L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us12.list-manage.com","uuid":"myuuid","lid":"mylid"})
         }
       );

       document.cookie = "MCPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;";
       document.cookie = "MCPopupSubscribed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;";
     }

     document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {showMailingPopUp()};
   </script>
   ```
3. Calling `newsletter.html` with an include added to `masthead.html` right before `</body>` with:

   ```
   {% include newsletter.html %}
   ```
4. No luck with all above :-(

**Any pointers on how to fix it?**

Comment: It can be interesting to see a repository. Any url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with javascript loading order. Jquery loads after your newsletter code, that's what creates an error.

- remove `{% include newsletter.html %}` in ***_includes/masthead.html***
- add `{% include newsletter.html %}` in ***layout/default.html***, just before the closing `</body>`

And it works !

Bonus : You can also remove extra `<body>` and `</body>` tags in ***_includes/masthead.html***